# FB.login() called before FB.init() - Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, facebook-authentication, flutter-facebook-login

**Trying to:**
Authorize via facebook login on **web**

**Problem:**
I get the error: `FB.login() called before FB.init()`.

**What I'm doing:**
I'm using package `flutter_facebook_auth: ^5.0.6` for my flutter project. It works fine with **Android** and **iOS**, but fails on **web**.

The `main.dart`-file initialises facebook before I call the login, so I'm not sure what I need to do. This is my main-file:

```dart
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  if(kIsWeb){
    await FacebookAuth.i.webAndDesktopInitialize(
        appId: "provided in the real code",
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true,
        version: "v14.0"
    );
  }
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  runApp(const ProviderScope(child: App()));
}
.
.
.
```